# Problem with Php Javascript Multistep Form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, multi-step

I have a problem with a php multistep form which should normally switch between different steps/forms in one single page.

However, **when I click on the first "Next" button**, instead of sliding to the next element, **the page refreshes and displays the first step/form**.

```
<button class="firstNext next">Next</button>
```

I hope someone can help me. Below are the CodePen references:

Debug CodePen : *https://cdpn.io/ibx/debug/KKMzjJQ/PNrvYKqamoKM* 
Code: CodePen : *https://codepen.io/ibx/pen/KKMzjJQ*

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you click the next button in Codepen you get the following error message :A link in this Pen has a missing `href` value, or this Pen is trying to change the document.location. Since this is a form it looks as though the entire form is trying to be submitted. You will need to add this.preventDefault() to each of your addListener events. This prevents the buttons event from bubbling up to the form event.

Comment: I have added `this.preventDefault()`  after `function(){`  but the same error seems to persist.

Comment: I have changed the code to this and it worked! 
`nextBtnFirst.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code to this and it worked! 
`nextBtnFirst.addEventListener("click", (event) => {   event.preventDefault();`